# Unity Google Play Games plugin v11.01 Authorization code (token) is null

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, null, token, google-play-games

After successfully logging into the account, I am trying to get an authorization token for the backend. But it is constantly empty. Is there some code missing, or maybe it's the sha-1 fingerprints or something else?

```
private void Start()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    LoginGooglePlayGames();
}

private void LoginGooglePlayGames()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((success) =>
    {
        if (success == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Login with Google Play games successful.");

            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(true, code =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Authorization code: " + code);
                Token = code;
                OnGetAuthToken?.Invoke(code);
            });
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("Failed to retrieve Google play games authorization code");
        }
    });
}
```